# Defining variable outside of the class vs using it as a property inside the class

Tags: javascript, class

I'm not sure about the definition of **cookieExists** outside of the **ieAlert** class.
Is it ok that the variable **cookieExists** is outside of the class **ieAlert**?
Or should I define it as a property inside the class definition?

```
var cookieExists = document.cookie.indexOf('ie11_cookie') >= 0;

class ieAlert {

  // Method for checking if IE11
  static isIE() {  
    return window.navigator.userAgent.match(/(MSIE|Trident)/);
  }
  // Method for setting a cookie
  static createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
      var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
  }
}


if (!ieAlert.isIE() && !cookieExists) {
  window.alert("Your browser is outdated!");
  ieAlert.createCookie('myCookie', 'ie11_cookie', 1);
}

module.exports = ieAlert;
```

Comment: Whether it is a variable or a property, that's OK. However in case of a property, it must be static, and it must be defined outside of the `ieAlert` class.

Comment: Side note: If your class is not intended to ever be instantiated (like with `new`), then I would define it as an object literal instead: `const ieAlert = {` -- and leave out the `static` keywords.

Comment: For future reference, I suggest that you close the loop on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56923441/1541563) before asking a new, heavily related question in a short span of time. Sometimes studying the answers on the previous question will help to answer other related questions you have, and will avoid the appearance that you're [asking Stack Overflow to write your code for you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274630/1541563).

Comment: @trincot that's exactly what I wrote [in my last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56923797/1541563)

Answer (score 2):

By following [the advice I already gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56923797/1541563), you could simply define `cookieExists` as a property of `ieAlert`. If you want the property access to re-evaluate the condition each time, then define it as a [getter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
const ieAlert = {
  // Method for checking if IE11
  isIE () {  
    return /MSIE|Trident/.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
  },
  get cookieExists () {
    return document.cookie.includes('ie11_cookie');
  },
  // Method for setting a cookie
  createCookie (name, value, days) {
    const cookie = [`${name}=${value}`, 'path=/'];

    if (days) {
      const date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
      cookie.splice(1, 0, `expires=${date.toGMTString()}`);
    }

    document.cookie = cookie.join('; ');
  }
};

if (!ieAlert.isIE() && !ieAlert.cookieExists) {
  window.alert("Your browser is outdated!");
  // ieAlert.cookieExists === false
  ieAlert.createCookie('myCookie', 'ie11_cookie', 1);
  // ieAlert.cookieExists === true
}

module.exports = ieAlert;
```

Comment: Thanks. But could you please explain why do I need this line: document.cookie = cookie.join('; ');

Comment: @user1941537 because in my suggested implementation, `cookie` is an array, not a string. You have to join the array elements together with `; ` as the separator to make it equivalent to your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might need some more explanation regarding what you're looking to accomplish. Ran on its own, this code would execute without `cookieExists` being a class property.

However, since you're exporting it the class, I assume the question is pertaining to how this would operate as a module.

When this module is required and its code is loaded and evaluated, it will evaluate and execute the conditional expression. However, since the sole export is `class ieAlert`, and the evaluation of the conditional expression is not a part of that class at all, the result of evaluating the additional expression is what is known as a **side effect** of the module. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127479/es6-import-for-side-effects-meaning) for more explanation.

This module would potentially affect the scope beyond defining the class `ieAlert`. In general, this wouldn't be recommended.

Maybe you could define a method of `class ieAlert` like so:

```
static findCookie() {
   return document.cookie.indexOf('ie11_cookie') >= 0;
}
```

That way, you can have more control over when the evaluation occurs.